# Fancy Chapter Heading

Tags: sectioning

[image]

How can I write my chapter headings in LaTeX like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: use the titlesec package

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use the »[quotchap](http://ctan.org/pkg/quotchap)« package. It defines exactly this chapter style. But that is *not* the main purpose of this package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[newcentury]{quotchap}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**Addendum:**

As mentioned in a comment, you an also use »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« to get that chapter style.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
  \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
  \fontsize{100}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
  \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{gray!75}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries}
{\filleft\chapnumfont\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}
{-24pt}
{\Huge}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: @ThorstenDoing Let's say I want to add the word `Chapter` to the title in the `quotechap` answer (e.g., https://ibb.co/fFHWna). How can I do that?