# Does anyone know how to set the chapter style like the image?

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, templates

[image]

It may be just a name of package or of a font but I don't know the name so I would like to write it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation of `titlesec`, and its `\titleformat` command.

Comment: Closely related and possible duplicate: [Fancy Chapter Heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134435/134144). [Chapter header with super huge numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139366/134144) and its comments might also be interesting/helpful.